# Very simple but: how to exchange views?

Tags: cocoa-touch

probably very stupid:

my iPhone app has two views: Login and and one where the user can do stuff. When starting the login view is shown. If login button is clicked I remove the current view from the main window's subviews and add the new one instead.

Am I doing this correct? I read so much stuff today about "how to develop" that I am unsure about such a simple thing as exchanging views now.

René

Comment: Are you working with view controllers? If not, why not?

Comment: In this case: no. But I could. So I add a view controller to my main XIB and add its view to the window's subviews. But then when switching to another view I have the same problem, right? Or do I misinterpret your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting wiser and therefore I answer myself: the solution really is to remove the view by using [revomveFromSuperView] (or whatever it is called in ObjC - I use MonoTouch) and then add the new view.

Answer (score 0):

If your app will only ever have 2 views, I recommend that you use the "Utility" template in Xcode.  It essentially works as 2 views and gives a button to flip between them.

Comment: Hm, I think it might have more views. But they are not connected. So Utility is not enough and toolbar is not an option either (as you cannot switch between login screen and the other screen). But basically: is it okay what I?